# Firesheep - Secure Public Network

Tags: c, wifi

**Assumption :** Open wifi networks are susceptible to software like firesheep but WPA2 Enterprise networks are safe.  (Thanks for the clarification TheBigO)

To avoid the security issues of firesheep, I am wanting to create a WPA2 Enterprise network that accepts any password - therefore acting like a public wifi network.

Using which libraries and preferably c could I create a WPA encrypted wifi network that *accepts any password*?

**Other options are welcome provided they make a "secure public network."** :)

**Edit:** Unfortunately I didn't ever accomplish the task of accepting any password for the wpa 2 enterprise network.  I felt a correct answer needed to be given.

Comment: If any user can connect to the network, can't any user run firesheep and thus listen to the traffic?

Comment: If you use a WPA2 Enterprise network, encryption is done on a per user basis, and thus firesheep can't monitor other user's traffic on your network.

Comment: @Mark I had thought the same thing but figured I should ask.

Comment: Why do you need "libraries and c" to create this network? Go to your router's control panel and turn on WPA2 Enterprise, if it supports it.

Comment: Using a desktop with ubuntu installed for the wireless network, and not exactly knowing how or if a secure public network was possible, I needed to connect my concept to programming.  I tried googling the concept but had little progress.  Due you have any recommended guides/tutorials for in depth understanding of wifi networks and concepts.  I want to understand but I'm not sure of any communities or sources to learn from.

Comment: [{codebutler}](http://codebutler.com/firesheep-a-day-later) has an article that provides interesting information regarding this topic. You'll have to scroll down to the section concerning WiFi.

Comment: You might want to ask a related question over at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/). Since those folks often run enterprises and worry about security, they might have useful opinions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this will approach will work; even if you allow the router to accept any password, it will probably still need to advertise itself as being WPA2 encrypted, in order for standard computers to set up communication with the router in the standard WPA2 manner, which will still lead to a password prompt, which means you'll still be asked what the password is, and you'll still need to tell your customers that they can enter anything, so you might as well tell them a specific password that they should type. Why not just advertise the password in the SSID, like "free-wifi-password-is-LOLZ"?

Comment: I had a hunch this might be the case.  I still think it would be nice to accept any password.  All I need is the c source code for the library that validates wpa2, and then I can skip the passcode check.  Especially since the pass code must be at least 8 characters long, it would be convenient if the user didn't have to get it perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Anybody can use a man-in-the-middle technique to bypass a wap wifi and still use a `firesheep` and some `arpspoof` to do the job. The safest way is to have the user always use https. Maybe force ssl usage on chrome...

Comment: firesheep is not effective on WPA2 Enterprise networks, and in certain scenarios https can be overrun using a men in the middle attack.  At least that is what I have gotten from the info around